# Azure functions - there is chance to install packages via apt-get?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans, kudu

My azure functions needs some linux package to work, but i cant install them by apt-get, because i get error "sudo command not found" or "(Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied).

So my question is: There is any chance to install these packages without sudo?
Im using Bash in Azure App Service(kudu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build and run your Azure [Functions from a custom container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp). This way you can also install other packages.

[This](https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2019/06/25/customised-serverless-using-azure-functions-docker-and-kubernetes-event-driven-architecture-keda/) sample project does pretty much exactly that.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:2.0

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

# Install FFMPEG
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ffmpeg

RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    npm install
```

[Source](https://github.com/sjwaight/CustomisedAzureFunctionsContainers/blob/master/Dockerfile)