# Installing non-pip or apt packages in azure when using func azure functionapp publish

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm publishing my azure function app using a Linux plan and I require some dependencies which are not accessible via pip. I've been able to publish the function with all `pip` dependencies using a `requirements.txt` file. Is there any other file which I could use to tell azure to (for example) run `apt install libevent-dev`?

I'm aware of the `--additional-packages` flag listed in the `func azure functionapp publish --help` docs. However I would ideally like a file where I can write any bash command. This way I could install any package with some bash commands like:

```bash
wget -P /tmp https://github.com/someacct/somepackage.deb
apt install /tmp/somepackage.deb
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

- AFAIK, unfortunately there is no such file to install non-pip packages.
- But as mentioned in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469401/azure-functions-there-is-chance-to-install-packages-via-apt-get) answer, **you can achieve your requirement using Docker.**
- Create a Dockerfile in your project and add the below configuration:

***Dockerfile:***

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10

ENV  AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot  \
     AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

RUN  pip  install  -r  /requirements.txt
RUN  wget -P /tmp https://github.com/someacct/somepackage.deb  &&  \
     apt-get install /tmp/somepackage.deb

COPY  . /home/site/wwwroot
```

- Install Docker and signin
- Create a repository in Docker Hub and note the name:

[image]

Run the below commands in *VScode* to build and push the Docker image :

```
docker build --tag <DOcker_ID/Image_name:tag> .
docker run -p 8080:80 -it <DOCKER_ID/Image_name:tag>
docker push <DOCKER_ID/Image_name:tag>
```

***You can refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deploy-container-apps?tabs=docker%2Cbash&pivots=programming-language-python) to create the docker image of Azure functions and deploy it to Azure.***

---

I tried with `apt-get install libevent-dev` in my project:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY requirements.txt /
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apt-get install libevent-dev
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! From what I can tell you're creating a docker image and pushing the image to a container registry. How do you then reference this docker image when you're using the command `func azure functionapp publish ...` to publish your application?

Comment: You can follow the [Msdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deploy-container-apps?tabs=docker%2Cbash&pivots=programming-language-python) link which I have given in the answer to deploy the docker image to Azure.

Comment: The MSDoc references how to create from scratch with `az functionapp create ...`. However, all the resources are already created in my case, so I just need to publish using the new image.

Comment: You can just create dockerfile in root directory of your project and add the contents I have given.

Comment: You can follow the document from [Build the Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deploy-container-apps?tabs=docker%2Cbash&pivots=programming-language-python#build-the-container-image-and-verify-locally)

Comment: The Build the Image resource details how to create and launch it using the `azure containerapp` command, not the `functionapp` command, which my question focuses on. This doesn't solve my problem without having to refactor to use `containerapp`. It does sound like the most reasonable command for my application though.